# Split TFLite model into two submodels

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a trained TF model which has the following architecture:

Inputs:
`word_a`, one-hot representation, vocab-size: `50000`
`word_b`, one-hot representation, vocab-size: `50`

Output:
`probs`, size: `1x10000`

The network consists of embedding lookup of `word_a` of size `1x100` (`dense_word_a`) from an embedding matrix. `word_b` is transformed into a similar vector using a Character CNN into a dense vector of size `1x250`. Both the vectors are concatenated into a `1x350` vector and using a decoder layer and sigmoid we're mapping it to the output layer and sigmoid with vector size `1x10000`.

I need to run this model on the client, and for this I'm converting it to TFLite. 
However, I also need to break the model into two sub-models with the following inputs and outputs:

Model 1:
Inputs:
`word_a`: one-hot representation, (`1x50000`) vocab-size: `50000`

Output:
`dense_word_a`: dense word-embedding looked up from embedding matrix (`1x100`)

Network:
Simple embedding lookup for `word_a` from embedding matrix.

Model 2:
Inputs:
`dense_word_a`: embedding for `word_a` received from Model 1. (`1x100`).
`word_b`, one-hot representation, vocab-size: `50` (`1x50`)

Output:
`probs`, size: `1x10000`

In Model 1, the input `word_a` is a placeholder and `dense_word_a` is a variable. In Model 2, `dense_word_a` is a placeholder and it's value is concatenated with the `word_b`'s embedding.

The embeddings in my model are not pre-trained, and are trained as part of the model training process itself. So I need to train the model as a combined model but during inference I want to break it up into Model 1 and Model 2 as described above.

The idea is to run the Model 1 on server side and pass the embedding values to client so it can perform inference using `word_b` and not have a 5MB embedding matrix on the client. So, I'm not constrained on the size of Model 1, but since Model 2 runs on the client I need it to be small.

**Here's what I've tried:**
1. During model freezing time, I freeze the full model but in the output nodes list I also add the variable name `dense_word_a` along with `probs`. I then convert the model to TFLite. During inference, I'm able to see the `dense_word_a` output as a `1x100` vector. This seems to work fine. I'm also getting the `probs` as output,

For generating Model 2, I just remove the `dense_word_a` variable and convert it into a placeholder (using `tf.placeholder`), remove the placeholder for `word_a` and freeze the graph again.

However, I'm not able to match the `probs` value. The `probs` vector generated by the full model don't match with the `probs` values vector generated by Model 2.

How can I go about breaking the model into sub-models and also match the results?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you described should work.

Is it easy to reproduce the problem that you're seeing? If you can isolate the reproducible steps and you believe there's a bug, could you [file a bug on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues)? Thanks!